# Inbox messages in SFMC does not work with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush, inbox, mobilestudio

I am trying to add AMPscript to the inbox message (MobilePush).

The AMPscript added to the Inbox subject line ( default SFMC field inside inbox) or other custom fields like body,cta etc. does not work at all.

This is the below ampscript code I am using and there are no errors -

```
 %%[ 
    SET @business_unit = AttributeValue("business_unit") 
    IF (@business_unit == "US") 
       THEN Set @ans= "its US TEST" 
    ELSEIF @business_unit == "IT" 
       THEN Set @ans= "its  IT TEST" 
    ENDIF
    ]%% 
    %%=v(@ans)=%%
```

Please can someone guide me how to troubleshoot this problem so that the AMPscript works in inbox message?

Note: I have tested this code in email studio against the send Data extension used for sending inbox messages and the code works perfectly.

I also tried using a lookup using the BU

```
 %%[
set @bu = AttributeValue("business_unit");
set @msg = Lookup("messagesDEX","message","BU", @bu);
]%%
%%=v(@msg)=%%
```

Even this did not work.

I also tried using a very simple code, by directly storing the message field in Send DE, still no success.

```
 %%[
    set @msg = AttributeValue("message")
    ]%%
    %%=v(@msg)=%%
```

Comment: Appears to be a Known Issue: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000pP3OQAU

Comment: You may have to retrieve it from your sending DE using the DeviceID/ContactKey as your lookup value.

Comment: Thank you for the info. 
I updated my question with the lookup I tried but please could you tell me how should I do a look-up? Thank you

Comment: I'm suggesting you lookup `business_unit` using `_subscriberKey`, where `_subscriberKey` matches the column in your sending DE that uniquely identifies the subscriber.